# When using computed collection, Vuefire duplicates docs in useCollection upon update of a document

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

this is a follow-up to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76445352/vuefire-how-to-declare-a-reactive-collection-using-usecollection-before-the-c), as I now face a slightly different issue: it's an update issue in my `userRecipes= useCollection(...)` array.

My collection `recipeRef` is declared as reactive data, as I do not know the user id when loading the app, which determines the path to the recipes collection (db>users>user.id>recipes>recipe).

```
const user = useCurrentUser();
const recipeRef = computed(() => {
    return collection(db, `users/${user.value?.uid}/recipes`);    
})
const userRecipes = useCollection(recipeRef);
```

It works when just loading or refreshing the page, I get all my documents with the right values.
However if I update a document (for example setting a "last viewed" timestamp) then the `userRecipes` array updates wrongly. For example, if it started with docs [A,B,C] and I update B to B*, then `userRecipes` will be updated to [B,B*,C] instead of [A,B*,C].

To rule out other issues, I've tested the same by hardcoding the path with a specific user id and not going through a computed collection. For example, if user.id = 123456, then:

```
const userRecipesTest = useCollection(collection(db, `users/123456/recipes`)
```

This test does work (I ran it concurrently), the updated fields of doc B will show in `userRecipesTest` as [A,B*,C] after the update.

So the source of the issue seems like the use of a reactive collection inside `useCollection()`. And as far as I've read the Vuefire docs this is allowed.